# Python dynamically set DNS record to IP (in code not by by changing hosts file)

Tags: python, dns

Is there a way to point a DNS record to IP by code?
Example:
Lets say `www.mydns.example` is pointing to IP `192.0.2.4`, which is the firewall address.
I want to run a python script from a serverless script (like Amazon's) to reach directly to my "real" server which is on IP `192.0.2.8` (bypassing the firewall)

When I run it from a server I can change the hosts file.
but I want to do it by code so I won't have to edit the local hosts file (which not functional with server-less function).

something like this:

```
url = "www.mydns.example"
response=urllib2.urlopen(url,ip = '192.0.2.8')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved by doing the following:

the URL should be with the IP address : `http://192.0.2.8/index/php` and using `urllib2.Request`, I configured the headers and added the domain under 'host'.

like this:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://192.0.2.8/',headers={'host':'www.mydns.example'})
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
```